# javascript replace all &#10;

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sting like:

```
var tmp='Hello &#10; I am &#10; &#32; &#40; Peter';
```

I want to replace all words with this pattern `&...;` to `'';`

How I can change the code below to make it work:

```
tmp=String(tmp).replace(/&#10;/g, "");
```

Thank you.

Comment: `console.log('Hello &#10; I am &#10; &#32; &#40; Peter'.replace(/&#\d+;/g, ""));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update regex with `\d{2}` instead of the `10` to match any two digit numbers.

```js
var tmp = 'Hello &#10; I am &#10; &#32; &#40; Peter';

tmp = String(tmp).replace(/&#\d{2};/g, "");

console.log(tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `/&#(\d+)(;)/g` .Its match the numbers upto reach of `;` end

[**Normal Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/HsrJrV/2)

```js
var tmp='Hello &#10; I am &#10;   &#32; &#40; Peter';

console.log(tmp.replace(/&#(\d+)(;)/g,""))
```

**Remove the Empty** space also use: `/(\s+)&#(\d+)(;)/g` .`\s+` match the empty space before the pattern

**[Empty space match](https://regex101.com/r/HsrJrV/3)**

```js
var tmp='Hello &#10; I am &#10;   &#32; &#40; Peter';

console.log(tmp.replace(/(\s+)&#(\d+)(;)/g,""))
```